# How to write a string regix in typescript take 'href' value?

Tags: string, typescript, substring

I need to take 'href'(tag link location value)  value from  following pattern html text. need some expert help to do it using typescript

String Text one

```
"<html><body><a href="C:\Users\K\Documents\docker_command.txt">docker_command.txt </a></body></html>"
```

String Text Two

```
 "<html><body><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">https://www.facebook.com/ </a></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const a = '"<html><body><a href="C:\Users\K\Documents\docker_command.txt">docker_command.txt </a></body></html>"';
const b = '"<html><body><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">https://www.facebook.com/ </a></body></html>"';

function getHref(html: string): string|null {
  if (!html) {
    return null;
  }

  return html.match(/ href=("|')([^'"]*?)('|")/i)[2];
}

console.log(getHref(a));
console.log(getHref(b));
```

Comment: Why is there `[^'""']`? Also this could match invalid format such as `"/test'` but I am not sure if that's an issue to @uma.

Comment: good point, @gurisko but assume , every time came correct format. but "there may be , many number of  <a></a> with links. i stil not test it.